# Taking Limits with Binomial Coefficients

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in taking the following limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{{n/2 \choose m}}{n \choose m}.
\end{equation}
Provided that $m$ is fixed the solution is:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{{n/2 \choose m}}{n \choose m}=2^{-m}.
\end{equation}
This can be seen by writing:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{{n/2 \choose m}}{n \choose m}&=\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!(n-m)!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}-m\right)!n!}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{\frac{n}{2} -j}{n-j}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^m}\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\frac{n-2j}{n-j}
\end{aligned}
and letting $n$ tend to infinity.

What however, can be said when $m$ depends on $n$? For example, if $m=\sqrt{n}$? Do we still have the quantity behaving asymptotically like $2^{-\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: The limit must be independent of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed $m$, asymptotically,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^m}\binom{n}{m}=\frac1{m!}
$$
this can be seen by writing
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^m}\binom{n}{m}
&=\frac1{m!}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)}{n^m}\\
&=\frac1{m!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{m-1}n\right)
\end{align}
$$
and taking the product of the $m-1$ limits.

If $m=\sqrt{n}$, then $1-\frac kn\sim e^{-k/n}$ for large $n$. Thus, asymptotically,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^m}\binom{n}{m}
&\sim\frac1{m!}e^{-\frac{m(m-1)}{2n}}\\
&\sim\frac1{m!}e^{-1/2}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(n/2)^m}\binom{n/2}{m}
&\sim\frac1{m!}e^{-\frac{m(m-1)}{n}}\\
&\sim\frac1{m!}e^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the ratio is asymptotic to
$$
\frac1{2^m}e^{-1/2}
$$

---

**Numerical Verification**

Mathematica 8, gives
$$
2^{1000}\frac{\binom{500000}{1000}}{\binom{1000000}{1000}}\doteq0.60653076090233049286
$$
and
$$
e^{-1/2}\doteq0.60653065971263342360
$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\dbinom{\frac{n}{2}}{m}}{\dbinom{n}{m}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}-m\right)!\ m!}\cdot\frac{(n-m)!\ m!}{n!}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!\ (n-m)!}{n!\ \left(\frac{n}{2}-m\right)!}.\tag1
$$
Since $n\to\infty$, we can use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation):
$$
k!\sim\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k\quad\text{as}\quad k\to\infty.
$$
Thus, we can use Stirling's formula to obtain the limit in $(1)$. I hope this help.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: @V.C. Ahh!? I've fixed it. Thank you...

Comment: The usual notation for asymptotic approximations is $f(n)\sim g(n)$ which means that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$. I give a more detailed exposition in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/731030).

Comment: @robjohn A new lesson. Thanks for your kindness. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the case where $m=np$ for $p<\frac 12$. We have:
$$
{n/2 \choose np}\approx e^{\frac n2H(2p)}
$$
where $H(q)$ is [binary entropy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function). Similarly:
$$
{n \choose np}\approx e^{nH(p)}
$$
Therefore:
$$
\frac{{n/2 \choose m}}{n \choose m}\approx \exp\left({\frac n2\left(H(2p)-2H(p)\right)}\right).
$$
We can check that $\left(H(2p)-2H(p)\right)$ is negative for $p\neq 0$ and therefore the limit is 0 for $m=np$ however the limit behaves as $e^{-cn}$.